# Best caching setting for webserver with continues deployment

Tags: caching, deployment, webserver

We use continues deployment and time to time we have some design changes. Like some days day ago, we changed the layout of our header, which results in completly different html and css code.

The css file is include build-specific with a hashtag, so caching is a problem here. But the HTML Code is read from cache by returning users. In combination with the css code the site looks like crap and conversion rates drop significantly.

We use the following HTMLS/HTML/HTML Caching rule via .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|htmls)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a better rule, so that the browser **always** checks for changes in HTML Code and serves the file **only** from browser cache if the webserver response with a 304?

Or what are the best practices for continues deployment and layout changes?